# How to extract the coefficient all the monomials of an arbitrary polynomial efficiently?

Tags: polynomials, coefficients

At present I know 3 efficient function to generate a list of all the monomials and the corresponding coefficients of an arbitrary polynomial. They are CoefficientRule, MonomialList and GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList. Is there any way can be faster than this 3 functions? Or any other language can manage this more efficiently?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.